# int from ArrayList to use in a different class

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

What I'm trying to do is make something that I can use to plan my workload over the year. I'm writing a program where I manually put in the Name of my class, the amount of pages and the difficulty of the class.

I'm working with one class where I put in all the data that I named earlier and another class that takes care of the calculating work.

Java Class containing the information about the college classes:

```
    public classInfo(String className, int classAmount, int classDifficulty, int classTime)
    {
        name = className; // name of the class
        amount = classAmount; // amount of pages
        difficulty = classDifficulty; // difficulty (1 = easy >> 3 = hard)
        time = classTime; // time you have (1 or 2 semesters)
    }

    /**
     * Prints all the data you have put in about this class
     */
    public void printInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Vak: " + name);
        System.out.println("Hoeveelheid leerstof: " + amount + " pagina's");
        System.out.println("Moeilijkheidsgraad: " + difficulty);
        System.out.println("Dit vak duurt: " + time + " semester(s)");
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
    return naam;
    }
}
```

I tested these methods and they all work like I expect them to. The last method (toString() ) is a method that I created so that I can print a list of all the classes that I saved in the ArrayList of my second class. The one that's supposed to do the calculations.

Here is an overview of my 2nd class: (the one that should do the calculations)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Planner
{
    private ArrayList<ClassInfo> course;
    private int index;

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public Planner()
    {
        course = new ArrayList<ClassInfo>();
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to add classes to the ArrayList
     */
    public void addClass(ClassInfo aCourse)
    {  
        course.add(aCourse);
    }

    /**
     * With this method you can print all the names of the classes that are currently in the ArrayList
     */
    public void showClass()
    {
        for(index = 0; index < course.size(); index++)
        {
            System.out.println(course.get(index));
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to calculate the workload of the classes.
     */
    public void berekenKlas()
    {
       /////// HERE IS MY PROBLEM.   /////
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how I can tell Java the difference between the different integers that I have saved in the ArrayList.

What I want to do is loop through all the classes (like in the method where I loop through the names of the classes) and saves the data of the "amount of pages" and the "time" to 2 different variables.

What I'm currently stuck on is that I don't know how to do this. Anybody who has an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you already have a loop, you obviously know how to extract the values. What do you want to do from there? What do you mean by "save the data?"

Comment: you can have two methods to generate the two pieces of data you need
`public int totalTime()
    {

        int result=0;
        for(index = 0; index < course.size(); index++)
        {
            result+=course.get(index).time;
        }
       return result;
    }

    public int totalDifficulty()
    {

        int result=0;
        for(index = 0; index < course.size(); index++)
        {
            result+=course.get(index).difficulty;
        }
     return result;
    }`

Comment: I'm really just trying to figure out how to tell Java the difference between the 2 integers that I want to use. Both of the integers are saved in the same ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use a foreach construct for your loop:

```
public void showClass() {
    for(ClassInfo courseItem: course) {
        System.out.println(course);
    }
}
```

But I didn't understand your question. You're already using fields to separate the different integers in ArrayList's ClassInfo type.

To save the two values you can create another class, depending of what you wanna do with those values.

Answer (score 0):

In your ArrayList you have ClassInfo object instances, not ints.
Each ClassInfo instance contains name, amount, difficulty, time attributes.

You can access to an attribute by using the . operator. For example:

```
public void showClass() {
    for (ClassInfo classInfo:course) {
        System.out.println("Name of class:"+classInfo.name);
        System.out.println("Time needed:"+classInfo.time+" semesters");
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Note the use of the for-each loop (it is like 10+ years old Java construct, consult with your tutor or the Internet). I found considering using standard indentation and adhere Java coding standards will make life easier :)

Comment: Thank you very much Gee Bee! Very helpful!